# kdb: What's the idiomatic way to join two tables by a composite foreign key?

Tags: kdb

I have two tables `t1` and `t2` defined as:

```
t1:([a:`datetime$(); b:`$()] x:`float$(); y:`float$());
meta t1
> c| t f a
> -| -----
> a| z    
> b| s    
> x| f    
> y| f 

t2:([t1:`t1$(); c:`$()] z:`float$());
meta t2
> c | t f  a
> --| ------
> t1| i t1  
> c | s     
> z | f
```

where `t1` defines a composite primary key from attributes `a` and `b`. `t2` defines a forein key `t1` to table `t1`.

I have looked all over the documentation how to join these two tables but had no luck. Is there a straighforward way to join them? I worked out the following way though:

```
ej[`t1;update t1:`t1$(a,'b) from t1;t2]
> a b x y t1 c z
> --------------
```

Basically doing an equal join between tables `t1` and `t2` after expanding table `t1` to expose the composite foreign key i.e. the column type `t1`. Is there a more idiomatic and simpler way? for example doing `t2 ij t1` leads to ``` error: ``a ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly more efficient & neater way to do this would be to utilise the hidden i column (i.e. row index) in kdb tables instead of generating the composite of the key columns of t1 & enumerating against t1 e.g.

```
q)ej[`t1;update t1:`t1!i from t1;t2]
a b x y t1 c z
--------------
```

This is slightly more efficient:

```
q)\ts:1000 ej[`t1;update t1:`t1!i from t1;t2]
11 1904
q)\ts:1000 ej[`t1;update t1:`t1$(a,'b) from t1;t2]
12 2256
```

(efficiency gain will be increased with populated tables, of course)

---

EDIT:

Another option is to use the foreign keys in a select statement something like:

`select t1.a,t1.b,t1.x,t1.y,c,z from t2`

This is considerably more efficient than using an actual join:

```
q)\ts:1000 select t1.a,t1.b,t1.x,t1.y,c,z from t2
2 1712
q)\ts:1000 ej[`t1;update t1:`t1!i from t1;t2]
12 2496
```

The downside here is having to name all the fields in the select statement.

One more option involving a join is to use the "t1" column from t2 to index into t1, and then join each record. To do this you'll have to use 0! to unkey the tables for indexing:

```
q)((0!t1)@(0!t2)`t1),'t2
t1 c  | a                       b   x         y        z
------| -------------------------------------------------------
0  gck| 2004.02.13T15:53:44.342 ndd 4.49731   7.833686 9.030751
1  job| 2001.07.22T05:29:31.118 hpb 0.1392076 4.099561 7.750292
```

(I added some dummy records for demonstration)

This is slightly less efficient than the select statement, but better than the ej:

```
q)\ts:1000 ((0!t1)@(0!t2)`t1),'t2
4 1920
```